# Best way to emulate hardware input?

Tags: input, keyboard, click, hardware, emulation

I used AutoIt because of its 
versatility and semplicity to solve repetitive problems on Windows. Now I want to try to improve the way my code works.

The major problem that I have encountered is to work with hardware input on a non-software level.
I want to use a "pure" input as I'm pressing a key on my keyboard or clicking on my mouse instead of emulating mouse-clicking or key-pressing with AutoIt.

I searched for a solution for several days on Google before asking here, and I had two ideas. Maybe they even work, but I'm sure that they aren't the best methods to solve the problem.

**1: Use C++ Keyboard/Mouse APIs** - But would it make a perfect emulation of a "hardware" signal or it could be seen as a virtual signal anyway?

**2: Use Arduino** - I have found APIs also for this for the same result. I thought this would have been good because it is about an input from an USB source. I can request the sending of a certain key as a keyboard could press a key by itself. Is it too intricate and exaggerated?

*However I'm probably wrong and you are laughing at these ideas because they are stupid and insane* :P

I have really a little knowledge of C++. If it is the best way to reach this target, would it be hard to learn only to solve the problem?

But the most important question is: **are those solutions good, or there are much easier ways?**

***Thanks in advance!***

Answer (score 0):

I do not think I fully understand the problem you are trying to solve here but I do have experience with using Arduino as a Keyboard/Mouse emulator. There is documentation for the built in Mouse and Keyboard Library here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseKeyboard. I will note that these functions will only work on certain Arduino models so be sure to check if it is compatible before purchasing an Arduino board. In my experience, it's easy to program and works quite well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply C:

My question is about finding the best method to emulate key-press and mouse-click perfectly like a hardware input.

AutoIt can be recognized as a software input, that's the problem.

I want to know if I can make this without an external device (like Arduino)  or if it's necessary.

However, just to be sure: which Arduino model do you have?

Comment: I actually used an Adafruit Pro Trinket (https://www.adafruit.com/products/2000) which is an Arduino compatible microcontroller. If you would prefer a vanilla Arduino board (less configuration required), I would recommend the Ardunio Micro (https://www.adafruit.com/products/1086).

Comment: I will consider which one to buy, because I already wanted to experiment with it for other projects - thanks for the suggestion :)

I would be curious anyway to know if the problem is also solvable without an external device. I'm talking about functions like those: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645530(v=vs.85).aspx
Is this suitable to solve my problem?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure if that would work/ how to use it. I don't have any experience with emulating keyboard/mice in software, but I would start with python + a python library, which should probably be fairly simple to code. This looks like it might work: https://win32com.goermezer.de/content/view/136/284/

Comment: I'm going to try in some days and I'll let you know, but I think that's not the solution. Wouldn't this be a simple input generated by a software?

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you are trying to do, but i think you are trying to make your computer to think you are moving the mouse, i have been looking for an answer to this problem for a few months, and finally i was able to move the mouse even in Fortnite (not easy at all).

I used a module i found in sendtex gihub's page (he says the author there), i leave you the the url to it.
https://github.com/Sentdex/pygta5/blob/master/keys.py

The module uses a library called ctypes, that provides C compatible data types, and gives you the the capability to call functions in DLLs or shared libraries.
you can find more information about ctypes here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html

As i am not an advanced programmer, i dont exactly know how it works, but i know what it does and how to use it. The module has a Keys class that contains all the functions, (only two of them really care, directMouse and directkey, the other ones are used to make the main ones work), and a few more classes that i dont know what the really do.

As you want to move the mouse, you might only care about the directMouse function, this fuction makes an instant movement of the mouse but not to the specified coordinates, it sums the current mouse position the given numbers.
This fuction also allows you to right and left click by giving the argument:

`buttons=keys.mouse_lb_press` for pressing the left button

`buttons=keys.mouse_lb_release` for releasing the left button

`buttons=keys.mouse_rb_press` for pressing the right button

`buttons=keys.mouse_rb_release` for releasing the right button

and you can combine a movement with a button action
for example:

`keys.directMouse(20, 20, buttons=keys.mouse_rb_press)`

This will sum to the current mouse position 20 pixels left and 20 pixels low and it will press (and hold) the right click button.

If you have not understood my explanation, i suggest you to see the code, at the end, you will find a sample code that will make a demonstration of the program working, you will see what it does and easily recognize how it works.

Hope i helped you.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @jhpratt Well sorry, its actually the first question i answer in Stack overflow, also, im not an english speaker, wich makes it harder to answer, and evethough i have programmed python for quite a while, i dont have so advanced knowledge about it, (and this is very advanced, i am just able to know what it does, but not how it does that). But i spent a lot of time looking to the answer of this problem that i wanted to save him some time. The only thing i could say about it is that the module uses ctypes, wich is a forgein function lib that provides C compatible types. I'll to improve the answer